# Why the copy assignment push_back element to the existing object?

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor

I created a class named Sentence:

```
class
Sentence {
public:
    vector<Clause> Clause_arr;
    Sentence() {};
    Sentence(const Sentence& s) {
        for(int i = 0; i < s.Clause_arr.size(); i++) {
            Clause_arr.push_back(s.Clause_arr[i]);
        }
    }
    Sentence& operator = (const Sentence& s) {
        for(int i = 0; i<s.Clause_arr.size(); i++) {
            Clause c = s.Clause_arr[i];
            Clause_arr.push_back(c);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Sentence(vector<Clause> a) {Clause_arr = a;}
    Sentence operator +(const Sentence& x) {
        if(x.Clause_arr.size() == 0 && Clause_arr.size() == 0) {
            Clause x;
            Sentence ans;
            ans.Clause_arr.push_back(x);
            return ans;
        }
        vector<Clause> a={};
        a.insert(a.end(),Clause_arr.begin(),Clause_arr.end());
        a.insert(a.end(),x.Clause_arr.begin(),x.Clause_arr.end());
        Sentence ans(a);
        return ans;
    }
    bool operator ==(const Sentence& x) const {
       if(x.Clause_arr.size() != Clause_arr.size()) return false;
       for(int i = 0; i < x.Clause_arr.size(); i++) {
           if(x.Clause_arr[i] != Clause_arr[i]) return false;
       }
       return true;
    }

    bool operator !=(const Sentence& x) const {
        return (*this != x);
    }
};
```

I created Sentence a and Sentence b, but when I do a = b, I found that it exactly gave me the result of a + b

I wonder how I can change my code to accurately implement the copy assignment. Do I need to change the constructor or the copy assignment function?

Comment: Can you show us `main` as well as expected vs. actual output? A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hint: What are the contents of `this->Clause_arr` at the beginning of `operator=`? By the way, I don't think you need to define a custom `operator=` at all for this class. The default one will do just fine.

Comment: A lot of your other functions can be simplified as well. Your `operator==` can just be `return Clause_arr == x.Clause_arr;`. You don't need a custom copy constructor or default either.

Comment: I think If I use the default  = ,it is the move assignment, and indeed in this program, i need copy assignment. @Kevin

Comment: @Jacob -- *I think If I use the default =* -- No.  As mentioned previously, your program doesn't need any user-defined copy assignment operator or copy constructor.  All you're doing with that code is to make it more of a chance that you've introduced a bug.  The compiler's default's are perfectly fine.  Except for `operator+`, most of that code is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to clear the contents from the `Clause_arr` instance variable in the `a` instance before pushing back the contents of the same instance variable from `b`.

```
    Sentence& operator = (const Sentence& s) {
        Clause_arr.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i<s.Clause_arr.size(); i++) {
            Clause c = s.Clause_arr[i];
            Clause_arr.push_back(c);
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

You might also use a range-based for loop.

```
    Sentence& operator = (const Sentence& s) {
        Clause_arr.clear();
        for (auto c : s.Clause_arr) {
            Clause_arr.push_back(c);
        }
        return *this;
    }
```